# Laravel 5.5 Dusk with GeckoDriver - Unable to locate element: body textarea[name='login_name']

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I'm unable to get the GeckoDriver version of a browser test to work.  If I test with the ChromeDriver everything works fine. Note, a $browser->dump() shows the page, the form and the element I'm trying to type->() into.

```
Build info: version: '3.141.5', revision: 'd54ebd709a', time: '2018-11-06T11:58:47'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: 'xx.xx.xx.xx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Here is the test:

```
  public function testExample()
  {
    $this->browse(function ($browser) {

      $browser->visit('/login');
      $browser->pause(1000);
      $browser->type('login_name', 'xxxxx' );
      $browser->type('password', 'xxxxxx');
      $browser->press('Login');
      $browser->pause(500);
      $browser->assertPathIs('/');
    });
  }
```

And here is the html section in the login form:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="login_name">Login Name</label>
                    <a href="/login/email" class="pull-right" tabindex="4">Forgot Login Name?</a>
                    <input type="login_name" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" name="login_name" value="{{ old('login_name') }}" tabindex="1">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <a href="{{ route('password.request') }}" class="pull-right" tabindex="5">Forgot Password?</a>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" tabindex="2">
                </div>
```